# Error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python

I am a newbie Python. When i am trying execute the below code watching this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OX49nLNPEE&list=PLsyeobzWxl7poL9JTVyndKe62ieoN-MZ3&index=18), i got an error. What to understand what is the error, why it is coming and how to over come it?

```
import sys
x = int(sys.argv[1])
```

Error:

```
x = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Than i started my Index value from '0'.
Code:

```
import sys
x = int(sys.argv[0])
```

Error:

```
x = int(sys.argv[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is the name of your python script (not an integer); `sys.argv[1]`  the first argument on the command line (if there is any)... try to `print(sys.argv)`...

Comment: What's the command that you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running that code from Pycharm itself, And pycharm doesn't pass those argv for you, and hence you are getting `ListIndex` error.To resolve this,  You need to start your `cmd` and then navigate to the directory where your file is and then.

`python <filename.py> arg1 arg2`

where arg1 arg2 can be anything, So long as you handle them correctly in your script.

```
x = int(sys.argv[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

This happened because PyCharm passes the name of the file as `argv[0]`. And in your code you are trying to convert the name of the file into an `int` which results in this error.

`x = int(sys.argv[1])` Wont work because PyCharm did not pass any values apart from the name of file at `argv[0]`. So `argv[1]` doesn't exist and Therefore you get the ListIndex error.

Comment: How to run from PyCharm ?

Comment: To pass values using `sys.argv` you need to run it as a script. So inside pycharm there is a command prompt, it will be beside the console. Open it and run the same command.

Comment: @user7406980 Updated my answer to show why you got those specific errors.

Answer (score 0):

As with all problems, break it down into smaller chunks.

First, run just `sys.argv`
You will see it is a list with an empty string. This means the out of index error is obvious because there is no item at a second index.

Next, you cannot use an empty string as an index with a list. That would be your second error.